# Catching SOAPFault in faultSequence

Tags: proxy, wso2, esb, soapfault, wso2-esb

My objective is to ensure that a SOAPFault originating from a SOAP service should propagate to the caller proxy's faultSequence (by default, it goes to the out sequence).

However, setting it up as documented (by setting the property `FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT`) seems to suspend my endpoint on the first SOAPFault. This doesn't look like the expected behaviour, as all subsequent calls show the endpoint as "suspended" even when it returns valid responses. 
The idea behind setting this property was to handle the SOAPFault in the faultSequence and then proceed as normal for other calls.

**Proxy setup:**

```
 <endpoint>
     <address uri="http://localhost:8088/mockItemsServiceSOAP?wsdl"/>
     <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
  </endpoint>
```

**Console log:**

```
[2017-07-03 14:01:57,861] []  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address http://localhost:8088/mockItemsServiceSOAP?wsdl will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
```

This doesn't block any major functionality - for example, it is possible to filter and treat SOAPFault as just another response in the out sequence - just that the property doesn't seem to work as documented.

**Doc reference:**
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULTSOAPfault